# Append Class After S3 Upload in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm using the [S3 Direct Upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload) gem, and everything is set up perfectly (uploads, has progress bar etc). I have a list of various documents to be uploaded, and I want to visually change each upload field after the user has uploaded something.

How do I select the div where the user originally dragged-n-dropped or clicked browse via `jQuery`, only after the upload has been successful?

`Coffescript:`

```
$documentUploader = $("#document-uploader")
  $continueButton = $(".btn.continue")
  $uploadSuccess = $(".upload-success")
  if isFileInputSupported()
    $documentUploader.S3Uploader
      remove_completed_progress_bar: false
    $documentUploader.bind 's3_uploads_start', (e) ->
      $continueButton.attr('disabled', true)
      $uploadSuccess.hide()
    $documentUploader.bind 's3_uploads_complete', (e) ->
      $continueButton.attr('disabled', false)
      $uploadSuccess.show()
```

Comment: Wont hurt to see some code. Maybe you can assign a css class to the div that generated the event through jQuery but I have to see the code to be sure

Comment: Added the `coffeescript` though I'm not sure how helpful it will be. I tried setting breakpoints in Chrome to explore how it was being triggered, but couldn't track down the initial call.

Comment: did you tried to catch the drop event in the divs with jQuery? something like this http://jsfiddle.net/fSA4N/5/ and also there should be an event that you can handle also with jQuery when the user clicks on the browse button, just make sure after you do that do not prevent the event from bubbling out or anything that could break your other code and sorry, I'm not into `coffeescript` for the moment

Comment: The idea is, assign an empty class to the div that generated the drop event, and then on the successful handler of the upload function you could look for that previously assigned class and add another one with the actual style that you want. Also for the browse button, if you're able to handle the event, you could use jQuery's `parent()` and/or `next()` methods to get the same div. Hope it helps you out